# Integrating $ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^4 (x) \cos(kx) dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Caveat: $ k \in N$

so after some 'repeated integration by parts I get and some 'evaluations',

$ k^2 G = 4G - 3  \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^2 (2x) \cos(kx) dx$

so this becomes,

$ G = \frac{3}{4-k^2}  \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^2 (2x) \cos(kx) dx$

now this result is already weird because if I put k=2 , becomes undefined. If I work it further, I get

$ G - \frac{3}{4-k^2} \frac{16}{k^3} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(4x) \sin(kx) dx$

Now how do I proof this integral is  '0'for $k>5$

And the values for $ k \in {0,1,2,3,4}$ ?

PS: please don't reduce $sin^4 (x)$ into linear factors. I want a solution finishing my 'parts' method

Comment: Why "PS: please don't reduce $\sin^4(x)$ into linear factors." sounds like "please don't do it in most simple and common way, I want it hard (with your hands, not mine)" for me?...

Comment: I think you meant $k=2$. Are you sure the integral that follows $4G$ doesn't have another $k$ in it, outside perhaps? That integral should  be 0 for all $k$ except $k=0,1,2$.

Comment: @alexy Burdin I was trying to solve $ sin^4 (x) = a_1 cos(x) +a_2 cos(2x)..etc$ using fourier tseries tricks If I did that it would defeat the point

Comment: @Alex R , yes k=2 , how do you proof that it is non zero only for k=0 and k=2

Comment: also @AlexR. What you mean when you say 4G does not have another k inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, I think the best way of doing this is to use the Chebyshev formulas to write $\sin^4(x)= 1/8 (-4 \cos(2 x) + \cos(4 x) + 3)$, and then to use the orthogonality of $(\cos(jx))_{j=1}^{\infty}$ when integrated over $[0,\pi]$. However, if you insist on avoiding this method, one approach is to convert everything to complex-exponentials:
$$
I_k=\int_0^{\pi} \left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^4 \frac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}{2}\,dx
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{32}\int_0^{\pi} \left({e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}\right)^4 (e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx})\,dx
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{32}\int_0^{\pi} \left({e^{4ix}-4e^{2ix}+6-4e^{-2ix}+e^{-4ix}}\right)(e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx})\,dx
$$You can foil this out and use the exponential rule; after a tedious computation, you get that:
$$
I_k ``=" \frac{24 \sin(k π)}{64 k - 20 k^3 + k^5} = \begin{cases}
\frac{3\pi}{8},& k=0\\
\frac{-\pi}{4},& k= 2\\
\frac{\pi}{16},& k= 4\\
0,& \text{else}
\end{cases},
$$which agrees with the original result (here $``="$ means equal, except at $k=0,2, 4$, where one should take the limit).

Comment: WHat is a chebyshev formula? what do you mean by the orthogonality thing? 

Thank you I can sleep in peace today because of your solution.

Comment: The Chebyshev formulas are a very powerful set of formulas that turn powers of sines and cosines into multiple-angled sums.